# How do I create a column in R that shows a cumulative amount over time?

Tags: r, cumulative-sum, sumifs

I have a dataset of three variables: identifier, date, and amount. I want to add a fourth column that shows the cumulative amount over time. For example:

| identifier | date | amount | cumulative amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| aaa | 01 | 5 | 5 |
| aaa | 02 | 6 | 11 |
| aaa | 03 | 8 | 19 |
| bbb | 01 | 5 | 5 |
| bbb | 02 | 4 | 9 |
| bbb | 03 | 0 | 9 |
| bbb | 04 | 11 | 20 |

In Excel, I'd use a SUMIF formula to create this fourth column, but I honestly have no clue how to do this in R. Can someone help?

Comment: Try `with(df1, ave(amount, identifier, FUN = cumsum))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a dplyr solution you can use mutate to add a column with the cumulative sum for each group.

```
    library(dplyr)
    
    df <- tibble(identifier = c(rep('aaa', 3), rep('bbb', 4)),
                 date = c(seq(1,3,1),seq(1,4,1)),
                 amount = c(5,6,8,5,4,0,11))


# A tibble: 7 x 3
  identifier  date amount
  <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>
1 aaa            1      5
2 aaa            2      6
3 aaa            3      8
4 bbb            1      5
5 bbb            2      4
6 bbb            3      0
7 bbb            4     11
    
    df %>%
      group_by(identifier) %>%
      mutate('cumulative amount' = cumsum(amount))

# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   identifier [2]
  identifier  date amount `cumulative amount`
  <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>               <dbl>
1 aaa            1      5                   5
2 aaa            2      6                  11
3 aaa            3      8                  19
4 bbb            1      5                   5
5 bbb            2      4                   9
6 bbb            3      0                   9
7 bbb            4     11                  20
```

Comment: df %>%
      group_by(identifier) %>%
      mutate('cumulative amount' = cumsum(amount))

How does R know to cumsum by the date with this code? Do I need to specifically call my column Date for this to work?

EDIT: This works perfectly. Thank you so much!

Comment: In this example, the Date column is not explicitly doing anything. R is considering each group in the Identifier column and cumulatively summing the Amount column, in order by row. So long as the data is arranged by increasing Date column, the cumulative sum will increase over time.

If your data isn't already organized by date, you can add a line between`group_by` and `mutate` :
`arrange(date) %>%`